# Как отредактировать файл словаря для PhpStorn

Tags: linux, phpstorm

Скачал словари для `PhpStorm` с расширением `.dic`. Случайно внёс не верное слово в словарь через `IDE`. Как его отредактировать через `IDE` или на операционной системе `Linux`?